# Site not vertically scrolling on mobile device

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I'm newer to html/css and am trying to deploy a very basic construction page, but I cannot figure out how to make it scroll on mobile.  This page will scroll if I test it within the safari browser developer tool for iphone on my desktop, but will not scroll on my actual iphone device. Can anyone help me figure out how to modify so it will scroll on the device?

```css
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,600,600italic");


    html, body, div, span, applet, object,
    iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,
    pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite,
    code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b,
    u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset,
    form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody,
    tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside,
    canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby,
    section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }

    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    body {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }

    mark {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: inherit;
    }

    input::-moz-focus-inner {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    input, select, textarea {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
    }


    /* MAIN */


    html {
        background: url(./assets/gray-wood-background.png);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 1080px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;

        }




        body.preload *, body.preload *:before, body.preload *:after {
                -moz-animation: none !important;
                -webkit-animation: none !important;
                -ms-animation: none !important;
                animation: none !important;
                -moz-transition: none !important;
                -webkit-transition: none !important;
                -ms-transition: none !important;
                transition: none !important;
            }

            body, input, select, textarea {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
                font-size: 16pt;
                font-weight: 300;
                line-height: 1.65em;
            }

    section {
        border: 1px solid white;
        margin: 5% auto 5% auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 70%;
    }

    hr {
        width: 80%;
    }

    h1 {
        padding: 40px;
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .logo {
        height: 100px;
        width: 333px;
    }

    .copyright {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 60px;
        font-size: .65em;
    }


    @media all and (max-width: 480px) {

        html {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }

    .logo {
            height: 76px;
            width: 225px;
        }

    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
        <head>
        <!-- meta -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

            <!-- links -->

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="construction-style.css">
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->

        <title>Developed by Gjoraas</title>

        </head>

        <body>


            <!-- <div style="background-image: url(assets/gray-wood-background.png); width:100%; height:100%;"></div> -->
        <!-- MAIN -->

            <section>

                <a href="construction.html"><img class="logo" src="assets/DGlogoTwhite.png" alt="Developed by Gjoraas logo"></a>
                <h1>COMING SOON</h1>
                <hr>

                <p>Our website is currently under construction.</p> 
                <p>Please check back soon to learn more about our web and app development services.</p>

                <!-- Copyright -->
                            <div class="copyright">
                                <ul class="menu">
                                    <li>&copy; Developed by Gjoraas 2018</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
            </section>






        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Perhaps there is not enought content to warrant a scroll. Try setting the height of `<body>` to 2000px or some such, or duplicate your `<section>` a few times to make sure the content does not fit on one screen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, all of the the content does not display but it still will not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the height larger, to 2000px, and then modified the height when under 780px to 1000px. Next, I changed the background image to be in the body instead of html. This combination worked for me.